# codeigniter solution no longer working on local box after changing machine name

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu

I have a web app called: (i substituted "LH" for "localhost" just for the purposes of this post)

```
 http://LH/myapp/index.php/welcome
```

In my config.php, I used to have:

```
 $config['base_url'] = http://LH/myapp/;
```

But in order to make it reachable from other machines on our network, I changed it to my machine name:

```
 $config['base_url'] = http://mymachinename/myapp/;
```

I can load my site from other machines now, except from the box itself. 
I'm running on ubuntu 12.04.  Is there anything else i need to do besides edit my /etc/hostname file?

Comment: open up your host file and point a domain name of your choice to the local IP address of localhost. 1.... something

Comment: Wait... why did you substitute "LH" for "localhost" for the purposes of this post? It wouldn't make the post that much longer to include the original and it would be less confusing.

Comment: @thez - because if you try adding localhost, it gives you an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, you are accessing your app from LAN

which means, your computer is using a LAN IP. Which is configured at your router (i.e. main network router).

From your local machine, when you open your website, if you do it through localhost (LH) it might not work but, open your `/etc/hosts` and **add your LAN IP with yourmachine name**, currently your machine name might be at 127.0.0.1 only.

Hope it helps. If it doesn't drop a comment :)